# The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true. Remove the condition

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I keep getting this warning and I am unsure how to resolve it. Help if u can please
Below is the excerpt of the code

```
String imageUrl = '';

CircleAvatar(
     backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
     backgroundImage: imageUrl != null
    ? Image.network(imageUrl).image
      : AssetImage(ProjectImages.placeholder),
        minRadius: 50.0,
     ),
```

Comment: Use `imageUrl.isNotEmpty` for non-nullable String instead of `imageUrl != null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this warning because you are declaring your variable **"imageUrl"** with and empty String.

**Note: Empty string and null both are not same they are different. So, to get rid of this warning you have to make your variable nullable like this**

```
String? imageUrl;

CircleAvatar(
     backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
     backgroundImage: imageUrl != null
    ? Image.network(imageUrl).image
      : AssetImage(ProjectImages.placeholder),
        minRadius: 50.0,
     ),
```

Your warning will be gone :)